# automatically make a display/editing control for data from database

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, controls

What is the best control/way I can use to show data from a database where the user can edit some data and can't for the rest.
I don't need to use data grid.
I need to read each data from the database and automatically make a display/editing control for it..

something like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable myTable = myRow.Table;
foreach (DataColumn nextCol in myTable.Columns)
{
  // filter out Name, Age, ID, Salary
  // if nextCol is Name, Age, ID, or Salary
  // continue

  // add a label and text box for next column
  Label nextLabel = new Label();
  nextLabel.Text = nextCol.Caption;
  // add next label to your control

  // add a text box for the next column
  TextBox nextTb = new TextBox();
  // add next text box to your control

  // assume your table sets up columns as write enabled or read only
  nextTb.ReadOnly = nextCol.ReadOnly;

  // keep track of write enabled text boxes - SEE BELOW
  if (!nextCol.ReadOnly)
  {
    dataCols.Add(nextCol.Caption, nextCol);
    textBoxes.Add(nextCol.Caption, nextTb);
  }
}
```

You need to keep track of text boxes that are write enabled and relate them to table columns so that you can update the data row when the user dismisses the dialog.  You can do this in a number of ways.  Off hand, this can be two Dictionary's, each keyed by the data column caption.  One dictionary contains the data column and the other contains the corresponding text box.  Then when the user dismisses the dialog, you can update the column value with the text box value.

```
Dictionary<String, DataColumn> dataCols;
Dictionary<String, TextBox> textBoxes;
foreach (String nextColName in dataCols.Keys)
  myRow[dataCols[nextColName]] = (Object)textBoxes[nextColName].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery datatable. It is editable too.

When the DataTables Editable plugin is initialized, it sends Update, Delete and Add requests to the server-side.
JQuery DataTables Editable plugin enables the user to select and delete rows in the table. When the user presses the delete button, an AJAX request is made with information of the id of the record that is deleted.

***Editing Cell Values***

Editing a cell is done inline by clicking on it. An AJAX request with cell position and cell value is sent to the server-side when the user finishes editing.

The update request has the following parameters:

**value** - the edited text

**id** - id of the record that is edited (id is placed in TR tag that surrounds the cell that has been edited)

**columnId** - position of the column of the cell that has been edited

**columnPosition** - position of the column of the cell that has been edited (hidden columns are not counted)

**rowId** - id of the row containing the cell that has been edited

The server should return the new value for the cell if the cell was successfully updated on the server-side, or an error message.

**Code to initialize jQueryData table**

You can use this code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this for asp? I use winform dear